# Batch ping not working

Tags: batch-file, ping

I am relatively new to batch programing and programing altogether, but after searching for hours I found to no avail, this is the script I'm having problems with

```
    set /p filename=What is the file name?:
cls

set /p lines=how many lines are there? (one number):

cls

set line=1

:batch_start
for /f "skip=%line% delims=" %%i in (%filename%.txt) do set "ip=%%i"& for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ping -a %ip% ^| find "Pinging"') do set ip=%%B& if '%lines%'=='%line%' goto done& echo %ip%& set line==%line%+1

pause

:done
echo Done!
pause
```

Please help as the code is ony setting %ip% and doing nothing else.

Comment: Instead of having so many things in one line why don't you use parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    set /p filename=What is the file name?:
cls

set /p lines=how many lines are there? (one number):

cls

set line=1


for /f "skip=%line% delims=" %%i in (%filename%.txt) do set "ip=%%i"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ping -a %ip% ^| find "Pinging"') do (
    set ip=%%B
    if '%lines%'=='!line!' goto done
    echo !ip!
    set line==!line!+1
)

pause

:done
echo Done!
pause
```

Is this working as you expect?

Comment: ECHO is Off (pause) Done (pause) (exit)